# Firestore reading on every listener open even if the 30 minute threshold is not met

Tags: reactjs, firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore

I will try and summarize our database structure but I understand this is hard to answer without the full picture.

This is how we have the database set up. We currently are reading in 3 different types of data: the users data, all locations associated with the user and all the devices associated with a location. Each have their own collection on the database and each are bunched together to have a listener on 10 documents at a time. Since the recommended amount of listeners at a time is under 100 we have built a circular queue so if a user has more than 150 locations or 500 devices that it will rotate between listening. Basically opening and closing the listeners. Firebase says it should not read if you close and reopen a listener under 30 minutes, but we are still getting reads.

This is not a problem with our queue however since the user listeners are not on the queue but are still rereading on reopen of the listener. It is an issue with the listener implementation. We are using react native and expo to build it and are setting the listeners in the App.js in a useEffect. Let me know if you need to see code snippets but we are basically just using onSnapshot method.

Here is an example of how we are getting the snapshot, which is in the createListener function called in App.js:

```
function createListener(route, query, callBack) {
    let unsubscribe = null /** the unsubscribe method to be returned by this function */
    const { collection, doc, subCollection, subCollectionDoc } = route
    
    ...stuff happens (basically check to see how far we need to go in the database. The example below is a get for a first floor collection.)

    let docRef = dbh.collection(collection)
    let queryRef = docRef /** declare queryRef which will have the querys applied to it */

    if (query && !Array.isArray(query)) /** if the query was given and it isn't an array */
        queryRef = queryRef.where(query.field, query.opStr, query.value)

    else if (query) /** if the query is an array we need to iterate through it and use the objects inside as parameters for the where method */
        query.forEach((queryObject) => queryRef = queryRef.where(queryObject.field, queryObject.opStr, queryObject.value))
        unsubscribe = queryRef.onSnapshot(function (querySnapshot) {
        let dict = {} /** this holds the objects returned */
        querySnapshot.forEach((item) => {
           dict[item.id] = item.data() /** set the objects id in the dictionary to reflect it's document id */
    });

        callBack(dict) /** execute callBack with the dict */
    }, (error) => {
                
        alert('failed to listen')
    })
    return () => {
        unsubscribe()
    }
}
```

Here is where we are calling it in App.js :

```
 useEffect(() => {
        console.log('Starting User Profile listeners')
        userUnsub.current = createListener({collection: 'users', doc: 'testUser'}, [], (data) => {
            setUserProf(data) /*userUnsub is a useRef of the listeners unsubscribe*/
            console.log('User got data:', data)
        }) /** create the listener for the user profile */
        return () => { /** return the unsubscribe function */
            userUnsub.current()
            console.log('Stopped listening to user profile.')
        }
    }, [])
```

Is this a problem with Firebase's side or is it more likely that it is our code?

Answer (score 0):

Okay so apparently you cannot unsubscribe per Luis from Google Support. They only listen if connection was hindered aka wifi issues and such.